# Location for public files in angular2 app

Tags: angular

I'm using ng serve to serve my angular 2 sample application. I created the sample application using the angular command line interface (CLI). I want to have a few jpg images in my angular application (company logo, etc...). However, I can't seem to find any folder which is public where I can put the logos and still have them visible. I have tried the following:

```
/src/app/shared/logo.jpg
/src/app/logo.jpg
/src/componentName/logo.jpg
/public/logo.jpg
```

I've also tried going to localhost/logo.jpg and localhost/componentName/logo.jpg and localhost/app/shared/logo.jpg and localhost/public/logo.jpg and localhost/app/logo.jpg but all of these produce a 404 not found error.

If I go to the standard http://localhost in my browser, I do get the angular 'app works!' message, so my server is working. I omitted the 'http://' from my previous links since stackoverflow only permits 2 links per post.

Where in the angular folder structure should I put a logo image that I want to be publicly accessible? Or where do I go to configure what folders are public in an angular 2 app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest `angular-cli` all static files go into the `assets` folder under:  `/src/assets`.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#project-assets

The folder name can be changed in `angular-cli.json`